# Firebase realtime snapshot listener using Coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, kotlin-coroutines

I want to be able to listen to realtime updates in Firebase DB's using Kotlin coroutines in my ViewModel.

The problem is that whenever a new message is created in the collection my application freezes and won't recover from this state. I need to kill it and restart app.

For the first time it passes and I can see the previous messages on the UI. This problem happens when `SnapshotListener` is called for 2nd time.

My `observer()` function

```
val channel = Channel<List<MessageEntity>>()
firestore.collection(path).addSnapshotListener { data, error ->
    if (error != null) {
        channel.close(error)
    } else {
        if (data != null) {
            val messages = data.toObjects(MessageEntity::class.java)
            //till this point it gets executed^^^^
            channel.sendBlocking(messages)
        } else {
            channel.close(CancellationException("No data received"))
        }
    }
}
return channel
```

That's how I want to observe messages

```
launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val newMessages =
            messageRepository
                .observer()
                .receive()
    }
}
```

After I replacing `sendBlocking()` with `send()` I am still not getting any new messages in the channel. `SnapshotListener` side is executed

```
//channel.sendBlocking(messages) was replaced by code bellow
scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    channel.send(messages)
}
//scope is my viewModel
```

How to observe messages in firestore/realtime-dbs using Kotlin coroutines?

Comment: Firebase callbacks are executed on the main thread by default.  I see you're calling a method called `sendBlocking` on the main thread.  Blocking the main thread is always a bad idea.  You'll want to find another way of working with the the Firebase SDK rather than blocking the main thread like this.

Comment: @DougStevenson I found solution

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What I ended up with is I used [Flow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-flow/index.html) which is part of coroutines `1.2.0-alpha-2`

```
return flowViaChannel { channel ->
   firestore.collection(path).addSnapshotListener { data, error ->
        if (error != null) {
            channel.close(error)
        } else {
            if (data != null) {
                val messages = data.toObjects(MessageEntity::class.java)
                channel.sendBlocking(messages)
            } else {
                channel.close(CancellationException("No data received"))
            }
        }
    }
    channel.invokeOnClose {
        it?.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

And that's how I observe it in my ViewModel

```
launch {
    messageRepository.observe().collect {
        //process
    }
}
```

more on topic https://medium.com/@elizarov/cold-flows-hot-channels-d74769805f9

Answer (score 16):

I have these extension functions, so I can simply get back results from the query as a Flow.

Flow is a Kotlin coroutine construct perfect for this purposes. 
https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-flow/

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
fun CollectionReference.getQuerySnapshotFlow(): Flow<QuerySnapshot?> {
    return callbackFlow {
        val listenerRegistration =
            addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, firebaseFirestoreException ->
                if (firebaseFirestoreException != null) {
                    cancel(
                        message = "error fetching collection data at path - $path",
                        cause = firebaseFirestoreException
                    )
                    return@addSnapshotListener
                }
                offer(querySnapshot)
            }
        awaitClose {
            Timber.d("cancelling the listener on collection at path - $path")
            listenerRegistration.remove()
        }
    }
}

@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
fun <T> CollectionReference.getDataFlow(mapper: (QuerySnapshot?) -> T): Flow<T> {
    return getQuerySnapshotFlow()
        .map {
            return@map mapper(it)
        }
}
```

The following is an example of how to use the above functions.

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
fun getShoppingListItemsFlow(): Flow<List<ShoppingListItem>> {
    return FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        .collection("$COLLECTION_SHOPPING_LIST")
        .getDataFlow { querySnapshot ->
            querySnapshot?.documents?.map {
                getShoppingListItemFromSnapshot(it)
            } ?: listOf()
        }
}

// Parses the document snapshot to the desired object
fun getShoppingListItemFromSnapshot(documentSnapshot: DocumentSnapshot) : ShoppingListItem {
        return documentSnapshot.toObject(ShoppingListItem::class.java)!!
    }
```

And in your ViewModel class, (or your Fragment) make sure you call this from the right scope, so the listener gets removed appropriately when the user moves away from the screen.

```
viewModelScope.launch {
   getShoppingListItemsFlow().collect{
     // Show on the view.
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you do in your getShoppingListItemFromSnapshot(it)? :)

Comment: The `offer(element)` method (as of KotlinX Coroutines 1.5.0+) appears to be deprecated in favour of `trySend(element).isSuccess` according to the [source code](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/a3a70bedca2189e248ed0be5844ddcb96cea9ae7/kotlinx-coroutines-core/common/src/channels/Channel.kt#L133-L169) (which also cites a GitHub issue: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/974)

Answer (score 8):

## Extension function to remove callbacks

For Firebase's Firestore database there are two types of calls.

1. One time requests - `addOnCompleteListener`
2. Realtime updates - `addSnapshotListener`

### One time requests

For one time requests there is an `await` extension function provided by the library `org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:X.X.X`. The function returns results from `addOnCompleteListener`.

For the latest version, see the Maven Repository, *[kotlinx-coroutines-play-services](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services)*.

**Resources**

- [Using Firebase on Android with Kotlin Coroutines](https://joebirch.co/2019/10/03/using-firebase-on-android-with-kotlin-coroutines) by [Joe Birch](https://twitter.com/hitherejoe)
- [Using Kotlin Extension Functions and Coroutines with Firebase](https://dev.to/rosariopfernandes/using-kotlin-extension-functions-and-coroutines-with-firebase-j0k) by [Rosário Pereira Fernandes](https://twitter.com/_rpfernandes)

### Realtime updates

The extension function `awaitRealtime` has checks including verifying the state of the `continuation` in order to see whether it is in `isActive` state. This is important because the function is called when the user's main feed of content is updated either by a lifecycle event, refreshing the feed manually, or removing content from their feed. Without this check there will be a crash.

*ExtenstionFuction.kt*

```
data class QueryResponse(val packet: QuerySnapshot?, val error: FirebaseFirestoreException?)

suspend fun Query.awaitRealtime() = suspendCancellableCoroutine<QueryResponse> { continuation ->
    addSnapshotListener({ value, error ->
        if (error == null && continuation.isActive)
            continuation.resume(QueryResponse(value, null))
        else if (error != null && continuation.isActive)
            continuation.resume(QueryResponse(null, error))
    })
}
```

In order to handle errors the `try`/`catch` pattern is used.

*Repository.kt*

```
object ContentRepository {
    fun getMainFeedList(isRealtime: Boolean, timeframe: Timestamp) = flow<Lce<PagedListResult>> {
        emit(Loading())
        val labeledSet = HashSet<String>()
        val user = usersDocument.collection(getInstance().currentUser!!.uid)
        syncLabeledContent(user, timeframe, labeledSet, SAVE_COLLECTION, this)
        getLoggedInNonRealtimeContent(timeframe, labeledSet, this)        
    }
    // Realtime updates with 'awaitRealtime' used
    private suspend fun syncLabeledContent(user: CollectionReference, timeframe: Timestamp,
                                       labeledSet: HashSet<String>, collection: String,
                                       lce: FlowCollector<Lce<PagedListResult>>) {
        val response = user.document(COLLECTIONS_DOCUMENT)
            .collection(collection)
            .orderBy(TIMESTAMP, DESCENDING)
            .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo(TIMESTAMP, timeframe)
            .awaitRealtime()
        if (response.error == null) {
            val contentList = response.packet?.documentChanges?.map { doc ->
                doc.document.toObject(Content::class.java).also { content ->
                    labeledSet.add(content.id)
                }
            }
            database.contentDao().insertContentList(contentList)
        } else lce.emit(Error(PagedListResult(null,
            "Error retrieving user save_collection: ${response.error?.localizedMessage}")))
    }
    // One time updates with 'await' used
    private suspend fun getLoggedInNonRealtimeContent(timeframe: Timestamp,
                                                      labeledSet: HashSet<String>,
                                                      lce: FlowCollector<Lce<PagedListResult>>) =
            try {
                database.contentDao().insertContentList(
                        contentEnCollection.orderBy(TIMESTAMP, DESCENDING)
                                .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo(TIMESTAMP, timeframe).get().await()
                                .documentChanges
                                ?.map { change -> change.document.toObject(Content::class.java) }
                                ?.filter { content -> !labeledSet.contains(content.id) })
                lce.emit(Lce.Content(PagedListResult(queryMainContentList(timeframe), "")))
            } catch (error: FirebaseFirestoreException) {
                lce.emit(Error(PagedListResult(
                        null,
                        CONTENT_LOGGED_IN_NON_REALTIME_ERROR + "${error.localizedMessage}")))
            }
}
```

Comment: I tried your awaitRealtime() extension function but it's not working for me. It emits only once with actual model in the firestore. After the emit continuation.isActive() returns always false. Do you have any idea why/how to keep it active?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @elementstyle! I noticed this issue last night and am working to resolve it now.

Comment: I've removed the condition `!value!!.isEmpty` which has resolved the issue. I will test throughout the day to ensure it is working.

Comment: Hi @elementstyle, the fix is working after 24hrs of testing. Please upvote the answer if it is working for yourself as well. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @AdamHurwitz, unfortunately it didn't help me. In my case after first emit `continuation.isActive()` returns always false so I don't receive data in the view. I'm pretty new with coroutines especially flows. If you can provide a sample code demonstrating all layers (data source, repo, viewModel, view) it could help me. For now I use [this liveData approach](https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/google-cloud-firestore/firestore-query-addsnapshotlistener-as-livedata/)

Comment: Here is the [Coinverse](https://github.com/AdamSHurwitz/Coinverse) open source code. The [ContentRepository.kt](https://github.com/AdamSHurwitz/Coinverse/blob/master/app/src/main/java/app/coinverse/content/ContentRepository.kt#L240) implements the `awaitRealtime` extension method above. Let me know if this clears things up for you and please star the project if useful as well.

Comment: This does not work for me, it says "No value passed for parameter onCancellation"

Comment: @Andrew, I'd recommend creating a new StackOverflow post with a minimal viable sample to showcase the code implemented and the error log.

Comment: Uhh I've implemented the code above? In "continuation.resume(QueryResponse(value, null))" it says -> "No value passed for parameter onCancellation".  I think you should check your code again because the API has changed.. Resume has two parameters now

Comment: Thank you for letting me know @Andrew. I will re-look at the current implementation of the code that is live in the open-source [Coinverse](https://github.com/AdamSHurwitz/Coinverse) app when I get a chance and update here if necessary.

Comment: Does the `awaitRealtime()` cancel the snapshot listener it registrates when it dies?

Comment: It's important to launch the coroutine Flow on the relevant lifecycle so that the Flow including the snapshot listener is cleared when the class launching the Flow is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me:

```kotlin
suspend fun DocumentReference.observe(block: suspend (getNextSnapshot: suspend ()->DocumentSnapshot?)->Unit) {
    val channel = Channel<Pair<DocumentSnapshot?, FirebaseFirestoreException?>>(Channel.UNLIMITED)

    val listenerRegistration = this.addSnapshotListener { value, error ->
        channel.sendBlocking(Pair(value, error))
    }

    try {
        block {
            val (value, error) = channel.receive()

            if (error != null) {
                throw error
            }
            value
        }
    }
    finally {
        channel.close()
        listenerRegistration.remove()
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```kotlin
docRef.observe { getNextSnapshot ->
    while (true) {
         val value = getNextSnapshot() ?: continue
         // do whatever you like with the database snapshot
    }
}
```

If the observer block throws an error, or the block finishes, or your coroutine is cancelled, the listener is removed automatically.

Comment: I found this such a great solution but I have a question. How can I handle the errors with this way ? I mean e.g how can i produce a toast message with throwing error ?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wrap `docRef.observe` in a try/catch block. When an error occurs it will stop observing the value and the catch block will be executed.