# Use Kotlin coroutines for real time Firestore updates

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, kotlin-coroutines

When fetching one-time data from Firestore, I can remove callbacks using the `kotlinx-coroutines-play-services` library:

**Using callbacks**

```kotlin
firestore.collection("Users")
    .document(userId)
    .get()
    .addOnSuccessListener { snapshot ->
        // Handle snapshot
    }
    .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
        // Handle exception
    }
```

**Using `await()` and coroutine**

```kotlin
try {
    val snapshot = firestore.collection("Users")
        .document(userId)
        .get().await()
    // Handle snapshot
} catch(exception: Exception) {
    // Handle error
}
```

I'm looking for a similar approach for real time updates. Is there an `await()` equivalent for `addSnapshotListener()`?

```kotlin
firestore.collection("Users")
    .document(userId)
    .addSnapshotListener { snapshot, exception ->
        // Listen to snapshot in real time
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Firestore listeners are not fundamentally compatible with coroutines, because they don't generate a single item for consumption.  You can't "await" a sequence of callbacks that happen over time (that have no distinct point of termination).

The most natural Kotlin concept that maps to listeners is [flow](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/flow.html). A flow can produce a sequence of values over time, and you can consume them in a coroutine context if you wish.  You will have to write some code to convert that listener into a flow (search those keywords to see what others have done).

Comment: to add up to Dougs answer, @real_shardul you will still need to use the addOnSnapshotListener callback to emit (offer) flows of data to your presentation layer to later collect them. Take care of not using LiveData in your repositories/datasource classes, instead use flow as its better to communicate between these layers to the presentation layer

Comment: Is there any benefit of using Kotlin flows with `addOnSnapshotListener`? The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55459961/firebase-realtime-snapshot-listener-using-coroutines) seem to increase boilerplate and some of them are using experimental APIs.

My use case is to update a LiveData object from `addOnSnapshotListener`.