# How to pass through livedata provided by Firestore SnapshotListener in a separate repository (MVVM)

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-livedata, android-mvvm

after hours of trying and searching I'm still stuck and hope somebody can help me.
I'm trying to get Live Updates from Firestore (using a SnapshotListener) through my ViewModel to my Activity, but all my attemps failed. Below is my current setup - trying to update LiveData in my Repository and handing it over to the View Model...

My problem:
I have UserData (inside a document) in my Firestore Collection. I try to listen to changes to the current user at runtime using the observeUserData() Function. The Data provided by this function (on Document Change) should be send through my ViewModel to my Activiy. If I change something to my User document in Firestore the SnapshotListener fires as expected, but the update is not reaching my ViewModel and therefore is not reaching my Activity.

Is anybody able to help me archive this? The only solution I see right now is to add a SnapshotListener within my ViewModel but as far as I know this is bad practice?
Thank you very much.

**Firestore Repository**

```
object FirestoreService {    
    val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    val userDataLiveData = MutableLiveData<UserData>()


    fun observeUserData(userId: String) {
        try {
            db.collection("userData").document(userId).addSnapshotListener{ documentSnapshot: DocumentSnapshot?, firebaseFirestoreException: FirebaseFirestoreException? ->
                firebaseFirestoreException?.let {
                    Log.e(TAG, firebaseFirestoreException.toString())
                    return@addSnapshotListener
                }

                val data = documentSnapshot?.toUserData()

                data?.let {
                    Log.d(TAG, "post new value")
                    userDataLiveData.postValue(data)
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error getting user data", e)
        }
    }
```

**ViewModel**

```
class MyViewModel (private val uid : String) : ViewModel() {
    private var _userData = MutableLiveData<UserData>()
    val userData: LiveData<UserData> = _userData

    fun getUserData() {
        Log.d(TAG, "getUserData called")
        FirestoreService.observeUserData(uid)
        var data = FirestoreService.userDataLiveData
        _userData = data
    }
}
```

**Activity**

```
//ViewModel Setup
val factory = MyViewModelFactory(user.uid.toString())
val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(MyViewModel::class.java)

//Initialize UserData
viewModel.getUserData()
viewModel.userData.observe(this, Observer {
    userData = it
    Log.d(TAG, userData.toString())
})
```

Comment: Please edit the question to explain in more detail what about the code here isn't working the way you expect.  Just saying that it doesn't work isn't enough information to work with - we need debugging information.  I suggest reading: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi Doug,
thank you for your reply.

I have UserData in my Firestore Collection. I try to listen to changes to the current user at runtime using the observeUserData() Function. The Data provided by this function (on Document Change) should be send through my ViewModel to my Activiy.

If I change something to my User in Firestore the SnapshotListener fires, but the update is not reaching my ViewModel and therefore is not reaching my Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your replies - fortunately I found my problem on this one.

I think i mixed up too much stuff from different "guides" / "approaches" - luckily I found Doug Stevenson's fantastic session below which got me out of this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WXc4adLMDqk

Thank you Doug :)

Comment: This guy's demo is titled "Firebase and Android Jetpack: Fit Like a Glove". It is very quite opposite. Am I the only one that finds this to be overly complicated and convoluted to hell?

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise your viewModel first

```
lateinit var userViewModel : MyViewModel

userViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
```

Then use the getViewLifeCycleOwner method on your userViewModel, and then observe the LiveData which would have your userDataModel

The onChanged() method would be where you can access the methods(getters & setters) within your userDataModel

Comment: Hey Damola,
thank you for your reply.

I have initialised my ViewModel in my Activity, just missed the snippet. Will Edit my post above:
//ViewModel Setup
        val factory = MyViewModelFactory(uid)
        val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(MyViewModel::class.java)

Answer (score 0):

There is a much easier way to do this *without any listener*. First, add this dependency:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.3.9"
```

Then lets say you have the following Repository:

```
inteface FirestoreService {
    fun sendUserData(uid: String): LiveData<String> // Or whatever it should emit
}
```

It's implementation which emits livedata could be the following:

```
class FirestoreServiceImpl : FireStoreService {
    val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

    fun sendUserData(uid: String): LiveData<String> = liveData {
        val mySnapshot = db.collection("userData)".document(userId).await()
        emit(mySnapshot?.toUserData)
    }
}
```

If you want to call this method in the viewModel, it would be better to change `LiveData` with `Flow`

```
fun sendUserData(uid: String): Flow<String> = flow {
    val mySnapshot = db.collection("userData)".document(userId).await()
    emit(mySnapshot?.toUserData)
}
```

In your ViewModel you than could do this:

```
val myInput = "TestUUID"

val myUserID = sendUserData(myInput).asLiveData()
```

And then, finally in the fragment / activity:

```
yourViewModel.myUserID.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
   // do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Hey Andrew,

I updated my coroutines-play-services - for some reason it was at version 1.1.1 - but unfortunately this does not help.

Don't quite understand the suggestion with the interface and implementation part, is the object alone not enough? The "FirestoreService" Object from my original post is the whole class.

Your suggestion on the sendUserData sounds interesting, but with mentioned implementation I would only receive the document once when calling the function - but I want to have "live Updates" on Document changes in Firestore - do you have any idea how to archive this?

Comment: @Sebastian You are right, I missed that part, sorry. I would refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55459961/firebase-realtime-snapshot-listener-using-coroutines) as it shows, how to implement a realtime listener with coroutines.

Comment: Hey Andrew,
thank you. I tried to avoid making database calls in my ViewModel as (if i understood it correctly, pretty new to the MVVM architecture) I should not mix up the Database and the ViewModel part - or am I wrong on this point?

I'm just wondering... if I only want to get a single document / value - my setup would be fine. I just can't get those updates to work.